# how to handle 404 error in jquery.post

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, .post

i do not know how to handle 404 error on $.post()??

```
$.post(url, data, function(returnedData) {
```

it can handle only the success data but i want to handle the 404 error also in.i know how to do it with ajax but dont know with this function please help.

```
    function returnData(url,data,type){
        $.post(url, data, function(returnedData) {
        if(type == "contacts")
        {   
        ko.applyBindings(new ContactsViewModel(returnedData,"#KnockOutContacts",url,data),$("#KnockOutContacts")[0]);   
        ko.applyBindings(new ContactsViewModel(returnedData,"#ContactDetails",url,data),$("#ContactDetails")[0]);   
        }
        else if(type == "logs")
        {
        alert(returnedData);
        alert(1);
        ko.applyBindings(new LogsViewModel(returnedData,url,data),$("#KnockOutLogs")[0]);   
        }
        else if(type == "sms")
        {
            ko.applyBindings(new SmsViewModel(returnedData,"#KnockOutSmsData",url,data),$("#KnockOutSmsData")[0]);  
            ko.applyBindings(new SmsViewModel(returnedData,"#KnockOutSms",url,data),$("#KnockOutSms")[0]);  
        }
        else if(type == "calendar")
        {
        ko.applyBindings(new CalendarViewModel(returnedData,"#KnockOutCalendar",url,data),$("#KnockOutCalendar")[0]);   
        }
        else if(type == "search")
        {
        ko.applyBindings(new SearchViewModel(returnedData,"#searchbox",url,data),$("#searchbox")[0]);   
        }
        else if(type == "location")
        {
        ko.applyBindings(new LocationViewModel(returnedData,"#KnockOutMaps",url,data),$("#KnockOutMaps")[0]);   
        }
        else if(type == "photos")
        {
        ko.applyBindings(new PhotosViewModel(returnedData,"#photogallary",url,data),$("#photogallary")[0]); 
        ko.applyBindings(new PhotosViewModel(returnedData,"#PhotosDown",url,data),$("#PhotosDown")[0]); 
        }
    });
}
```

i bascially apply bindings when i get data but when i dont get data it doesnt go inside the success function and thats breaking my js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a global error handler:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(e, xhr, settings, exception) {

});
```

Answer (score 10):

Read about `statusCode` callback [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/page.htm",
    type: "POST",
    statusCode: {
        404: function() {
          alert("page not found");
        }
    }
})
```

---

Edit.

Can also be accieved with `$.post`

```
$.post(url, data, function(returnedData) {
    //callback
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    if(jqXHR.status == 404) {

    }
});
```

Comment: i dont want to do this with `$.ajax`